# JSDOM + Ava – test function that relies on `document` global

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, jsdom, ava

I'm writing some utilities that are related to the `document` object.

Let's say that I'm writing a that uses `document` browser object.

```
// utils.js
export function myFn(callback) {
  document.addEventListener(callback);  
}
```

My test file is like so:

```
// utils.test.js
import test from "ava";
import { JSDOM } from "jsdom";
import sinon from "sinon";
import { myFn } from "./utils";

let dom, document;

test.beforeEach(() => {
  dom = new JSDOM();
  document = dom.window.document;
});

test("it calls the callback when document is ready", t => {
  let fakeCb = sinon.spy();
  myFn(fakeCb);
  t.true(fakeCb.called);
});
```

After running this test I got a ReferenceError telling that "document is not defined", which makes sense.

My question is: what would be a good way to make the `document` variable from my test be used inside the function under test?

This function works if I pass a `document` parameter to it, but this is an  ugly solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js provides access to the global namespace through [`global`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global).

Set `document` on `global` and it will be available in your code:

```
// utils.test.js
import test from "ava";
import { JSDOM } from "jsdom";
import sinon from "sinon";
import { myFn } from "./utils";

test.beforeEach(() => {
  global.document = new JSDOM().window.document;
});

test("it calls the callback when document is ready", t => {
  // ...
});
```